# CSS positioning - Rezising div to other div

Tags: css

```
<div id="container" style="width:300px;">
   <div id="leftBar" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
       //explanding text ... bla bla bla
   </div>
   <div id="rightBar" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
       //this bar has a background image that should stretch to a the left bars HEIGHT
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the rightBar to expand with the leftBar. I can't use a fixed value because leftBar includes text that varies in length. rightBar should be equal in height to leftBar.

Comment: `height: 100%`? I'm confused on the problem you're having.

Comment: You've just changed your source code. Can you provide your real HTML code you are having problems with? Saves people the hassle.

Comment: Stackoverflow Pro Tip: If you got the answer you were looking for, mark it as accepted by ticking the tickmark next to it. Also go back to your previous questions and mark some of them as accepted too. You have a 0% accept ratio and it will make it hard for you to get good answers in the future :D

Answer (score 1):

You can change the markup slightly and end up with this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftBar">
        <div id="rightBar">
            This is your 'rightBar'
        </div>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>       
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
        <p>Many paragraphs of text</p>
    </div>
</div>​​​
```

and this CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#leftBar {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

#rightBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    *height: expression(document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight); /*ie6 hack*/
}
```

This should work perfectly. [Check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mdqs/)